# WD Red vs Red Pro NAS Hard Drives

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, nas, durability

I'm looking for a **DURABLE AND RELIABLE** hard drive for a NAS and I've come to these bad boys.

http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-800002.pdf

http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-800022.pdf

Advantages of the Pro over the regular:

- 7200 RPM vs 5400 RPM;
- RAFF technology for better vibration protection;
- slightly better failure rate;
- 128 MB cache vs 64 MB.

Advantages of the regular over the Pro:

- larger temperature operating range: 0-65°C vs 5-60°C (seriously?!);
- **since it doesn't have RAFF technology and spins at a lower speed it produces less heat.**

And this is what drives me nut, on the long run, keeping it on 24/7, will the less heat generated by the Red make it more durable and reliable compared to the Red Pro? I will operate it in a 2 drives rack, so vibrations and performance is not a problem, I can sacrifice all for durability and reliability. Price is not a problem too. I fear heat though... Whoever has experience in this field is welcome, for your knowledge, which one will last longer without failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this drive for larger network it would be better for you to use the **WD Red Pro** because it suffice the needs of a larger group unlike the **WD Red** it is only design for smaller networks.

But **WD Red** is a reflection of the most extensive NAS partner compatibility- testing list that is available on the market.* That means when you buy a NAS enclosure, you can trust that WD Red will be the most compatible drive available.

Other hand, NAS for Big Business. Increase the efficiency and productivity of your business with WD Red Pro hard drives for your 8 to 16 bay NAS system. WD Red Pro comes equipped with NASware 3.0, which increases system compatibility allowing for seamless integration with your existing network infrastructure. Add value to your business by enabling your employees to quickly share their files and back up folders reliably with WD Red Pro NAS hard drives in your NAS solution.

Edit:

Okay, the **Red Pro will be much durable versus the Red**. Why? Because it has already its feature that it said that it has a slightly **better failure rate** and based on your statement there is the Red Pro has a vibration protection and it is also **Bay Shock Protection and a sensor that detects subtle shock**. As per **heat or power**, you just need a **good cooling system**. You just have to **keep in mind that maintaining proper air flow through your computer case** is the **better way to keep the heat at its lowest**, please be reminded that heat can build up inside to temperatures far hotter than the ambient temperature of your room. You are comfortable, PC may not.

Of course heat is an issue that why I am saying that you are the one should maintain it, no matter how much heat your drive can produce. Provide it with good airflow outside and especially inside.